# Impact of anti-depressant prescription on application for US citizenship

Tags: citizenship, us-citizens, greencard

I am currently in the US on a green card. I have now been in the US for around 7 years, and on an employer sponsored green card for 3 years.

I have just used an online service to get an SSRI prescription, which has helped a lot with anxiety.

I would prefer to see a primary care provider to receive a prescription, but I am concerned that it could impact an application for citizenship. Could this be used against me?

Comment: Was the online service legal?  If so, how is it different from a primary care physician in terms of the impact on your application for citizenship?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a medical questionnaire or medical examination required to obtain US citizenship?